# How to create a link for wordpress meta datas?

Tags: post-meta, links, meta-query

I would like to create a link for "Leave a comment", which name "quick comment" (here come a ajax comment form on div).
How can I do this?
I have attached a picture where I'd like to put this link:
[image]

The function for this:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'cyberchimps_posted_in' ) ) {
   //add meta entry category to single post, archive and blog list if set in options
 function cyberchimps_posted_in() {
global $post;

if( is_single() ) {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'single_post_byline_categories', 1 ) ) ? cyberchimps_get_option( 'single_post_byline_categories', 1 ) : false; 
}
elseif( is_archive() ) {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'archive_post_byline_categories', 1 ) ) ? cyberchimps_get_option( 'archive_post_byline_categories', 1 ) : false;  
}
else {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'post_byline_categories', 1 ) ) ? cyberchimps_get_option( 'post_byline_categories', 1 ) : false;  
}
if( $show ):
            $categories_list = get_the_category_list( ', ' );
            if ( $categories_list ) :
            $cats = sprintf( __( 'Ebben a kategóriában:', 'cyberchimps_core' ) . ' %1$s', $categories_list );
        ?>
        <span class="cat-links">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'cyberchimps_post_categories', $cats ); ?>
        </span>
  <span class="sep"> <?php echo apply_filters( 'cyberchimps_entry_meta_sep', '|' ); ?></span>
<?php endif;
endif;
   }
  }

   if( ! function_exists( 'cyberchimps_post_tags' ) ) {
    //add meta entry tags to single post, archive and blog list if set in options
     function cyberchimps_post_tags() {
global $post;

if( is_single() ) {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'single_post_byline_tags', 1 ) ) ? cyberchimps_get_option( 'single_post_byline_tags', 1 ) : false; 
}
elseif( is_archive() ) {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'archive_post_byline_tags', 1 ) ) ? cyberchimps_get_option( 'archive_post_byline_tags', 1 ) : false;  
}
else {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'post_byline_tags', 1 ) ) ? cyberchimps_get_option( 'post_byline_tags', 1 ) : false;  
}
if( $show ):
$tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );
            if ( $tags_list ) :
            $tags = sprintf( __( 'Tags:', 'cyberchimps_core' ) . ' %1$s', $tags_list );
        ?>
        <span class="taglinks">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'cyberchimps_post_tags', $tags ); ?>
        </span>
  <span class="sep"> <?php echo apply_filters( 'cyberchimps_entry_meta_sep', '|' ); ?> </span>
        <?php endif; // End if $tags_list
endif;
  }
  }

if( ! function_exists( 'cyberchimps_post_comments' ) ) {
  //add meta entry comments to single post, archive and blog list if set in options
function cyberchimps_post_comments() {
global $post;

if( is_single() ) {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'single_post_byline_comments', 1 ) ) ?    cyberchimps_get_option( 'single_post_byline_comments', 1 ) : false; 
}
elseif( is_archive() ) {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'archive_post_byline_comments', 1 ) ) ? cyberchimps_get_option( 'archive_post_byline_comments', 1 ) : false;  
}
else {
    $show = ( cyberchimps_get_option( 'post_byline_comments', 1 ) ) ? cyberchimps_get_option( 'post_byline_comments', 1 ) : false;  
}
$leave_comment = ( is_single() || is_page() ) ? '' : __( 'Szólj hozzá', 'cyberchimps_core' );
if( $show ):
    if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) ) : ?>
        <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( $leave_comment, __( '1 hozzászólás', 'cyberchimps_core' ), '% ' . __( 'hozzászólás', 'cyberchimps_core' ) ); ?></span>
  <span class="sep"> <?php echo ( $leave_comment != '' ) ? apply_filters( 'cyberchimps_entry_meta_sep', '|' ) : ''; ?></span>
<?php endif;
endif;
   }
 }

// change default comments labels and form
    add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'cyberchimps_comment_form_filter' );
    function cyberchimps_comment_form_filter( $defaults ) {
$defaults['title_reply'] = __( 'Szólj hozzá!', 'cyberchimps_core' );
return $defaults;
    }
```

Comment: Can you also update the code you have started with for this functionality?

Comment: Yes,please wait a minutes

Comment: I'm doned,please view it